# Java - Semaphore release without acquire

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency, semaphore

I have threads which are given random number (1 to n) and are instructed to print them in sorted order. I used semaphore such that I acquire the number of permits = random number and release one permit more than what was acquired.

> acquired = random number; released = 1+random number

Initial permit count for semaphore is 1. So thread with random number 1 should get permit and then 2 and so on.

This is supported as per the documentation given below

> There is no requirement that a thread that releases a permit must have acquired that permit by calling acquire().

The problem is my program gets stuck after 1 for n>2.

My program is given below:

```
import java.util.concurrent.Semaphore;

public class MultiThreading {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Semaphore sem = new Semaphore(1,false);
        for(int i=5;i>=1;i--)
            new MyThread(i, sem);
    }
}
class MyThread implements Runnable {
    int var;Semaphore sem;
    public MyThread(int a, Semaphore s) {
        var =a;sem=s;
        new Thread(this).start();
    }
    @Override
    public void run() {
        System.out.println("Acquiring lock -- "+var);
        try {
            sem.acquire(var);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        System.out.println(var);

        System.out.println("Releasing lock -- "+var);
        sem.release(var+1);
    }
}
```

Output is :

> Acquiring lock -- 4
>   Acquiring lock -- 5
>   Acquiring lock -- 3
>   Acquiring lock -- 2
>   Acquiring lock -- 1
>   1
>   Releasing lock -- 1

While If I modify my code with tryAcquire, it runs perfectly well. 
Below is new run implementation

```
@Override
public void run() {
    boolean acquired = false;
    while(!acquired) {
        acquired = sem.tryAcquire(var);
    }
    System.out.println(var);
    sem.release(var+1);
}
```

Can someone please explain the semaphore's permit acquire mechanism when mulitple threads are waiting with different permit request??

Comment: I'm sorry I cannot answer your question, but. Do **not** do `new Thread(this).start();` in the constructor. As you are still in the constructor, the Object is not complete and you give a partially initialized object to another method, in this case even to another thread. This really really bad, don't do this. Better `extend Thread` instead of `implement Runnable` and then do `new MyThread(i, sem).start();` or do `new Thread(new MyThread(i, sem)).start();`.

Comment: Oh ok, I will verify this. Thanks for pointing it out.

Comment: @BjörnKautler rather than just saying "*This really really bad, don't do this.*" try to explain *why* so people can understand the underlying issue.

Comment: @dimo414 i did explain. If someone is wondering why it is bad to use partially initialized objects (really?) then they can Google. After all it is a comment with limited space and formatting possibilities.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's a clever strategy, but you're misunderstanding how `Sempahore` hands out permits. If you run your code enough times you'll actually see it reach step two:

```
Acquiring lock -- 5
Acquiring lock -- 1
1
Releasing lock -- 1
Acquiring lock -- 3
Acquiring lock -- 2
2
Acquiring lock -- 4
Releasing lock -- 2
```

If you keep on re-running it enough times you'd actually see it successfully finish. This happens because of how `Semaphore` hands out permits. You're assuming `Semaphore` will try to accommodate an `acquire()` call as soon as it has enough permits to do so. If we look carefully at the documentation for [`Semaphore.aquire(int)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Semaphore.html#acquire-int-) we'll see that is not the case (emphasis mine):

> If insufficient permits are available then the current thread becomes disabled for thread scheduling purposes and lies dormant until ... some other thread invokes one of the `release` methods for this semaphore, **the current thread is next to be assigned permits** and the number of available permits satisfies this request.

In other words `Semaphore` keeps a queue of pending acquire request and, upon each call to `.release()`, *only checks the head of the queue*. In particular if you enable fair queuing (set the second constructor argument to `true`) you'll see even step one doesn't occur, because step 5 is (usually) the first in the queue and even new `acquire()` calls that could be fulfilled will be queued up behind the other pending calls.

In short this means you cannot rely on `.acquire()` to return as soon as possible, as your code assumes.

By using `.tryAcquire()` in a loop instead you avoid making any blocking calls (and therefore put a lot more load on your `Semaphore`) and as soon as the necessary number of permits becomes available a `tryAcquire()` call will successfully obtain them. This works but is wasteful.

Picture a wait-list at a restaurant. Using `.aquire()` is like putting your name on the list and waiting to be called. It may not be perfectly efficient, but they'll get to you in a (reasonably) fair amount of time. Imagine instead if everyone just shouted at the host "Do you have a table for *`n`* yet?" as often as they could - that's your `tryAquire()` loop. It may still work out (as it does in your example) but it's certainly not the right way to go about it.

---

So what should you do instead? There's a number of possibly useful tools in [`java.util.concurrent`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/package-summary.html), and which is best somewhat depends on what exactly you're trying to do. Seeing as you're effectively having each thread start the next one I might use a `BlockingQueue` as the synchronization aid, pushing the next step into the queue each time. Each thread would then poll the queue, and if it's not the activated thread's turn replace the value and wait again.

Here's an example:

```
public class MultiThreading {
  public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception{
    // Use fair queuing to prevent an out-of-order task
    // from jumping to the head of the line again
    // try setting this to false - you'll see far more re-queuing calls
    BlockingQueue<Integer> queue = new ArrayBlockingQueue<>(1, true);
    for (int i = 5; i >= 1; i--) {
      Thread.sleep(100); // not necessary, just helps demonstrate the queuing behavior
      new MyThread(i, queue).start();
    }
    queue.add(1); // work starts now
  }

  static class MyThread extends Thread {
    int var;
    BlockingQueue<Integer> queue;

    public MyThread(int var, BlockingQueue<Integer> queue) {
      this.var = var;
      this.queue = queue;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
      System.out.println("Task " + var + " is now pending...");
      try {
        while (true) {
          int task = queue.take();
          if (task != var) {
            System.out.println(
                "Task " + var + " got task " + task + " instead - re-queuing");
            queue.add(task);
          } else {
            break;
          }
        }
      } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        // If a thread is interrupted, re-mark the thread interrupted and terminate
        Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
        return;
      }

      System.out.println("Finished task " + var);

      System.out.println("Registering task " + (var + 1) + " to run next");
      queue.add(var + 1);
    }
  }
}
```

This prints the following and terminates successfully:

> ```
> Task 5 is now pending...
> Task 4 is now pending...
> Task 3 is now pending...
> Task 2 is now pending...
> Task 1 is now pending...
> Task 5 got task 1 instead - re-queuing
> Task 4 got task 1 instead - re-queuing
> Task 3 got task 1 instead - re-queuing
> Task 2 got task 1 instead - re-queuing
> Finished task 1
> Registering task 2 to run next
> Task 5 got task 2 instead - re-queuing
> Task 4 got task 2 instead - re-queuing
> Task 3 got task 2 instead - re-queuing
> Finished task 2
> Registering task 3 to run next
> Task 5 got task 3 instead - re-queuing
> Task 4 got task 3 instead - re-queuing
> Finished task 3
> Registering task 4 to run next
> Task 5 got task 4 instead - re-queuing
> Finished task 4
> Registering task 5 to run next
> Finished task 5
> Registering task 6 to run next
> ```

Comment: Fantastic approach. Thanks a lot, I understand it now. We could use Atomic variable too instead of BlockingQueue or could use Condition to avoid polling mechanism.

Comment: @user1474053 glad to help. There's definitely a number of different reasonable solutions depending on what exactly you're trying to accomplish, but if you want to ensure separate threads act in a prescribed order you should use some sort of blocking mechanism; an Atomic variable would need to be regularly polled by all threads.

Comment: Is it possible to do something similar using pthread in C/C++? I've looking for that for a long time now.

Comment: @A.Mashreghi presumably, but I'd suggest posting a separate question with the appropriate tags. I can't say offhand what the right approach would be for C/C++.

Comment: @dimo414 Thanks for the suggestion. I just did: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58210460/c-c-single-semaphore-of-type-sem-t-to-print-numbers-in-order

Answer (score 2):

The Javadoc for `Semaphore.acquire(int)` says:

```
If insufficient permits are available then the current thread becomes 
disabled for thread scheduling purposes and lies dormant until one of 
two things happens:

Some other thread invokes one of the release methods for this semaphore, 
the current thread is next to be assigned permits and the number of 
available permits satisfies this request [or the thread is interrupted].
```

The thread that is "next to be assigned" is probably thread 4 in your example.  It is waiting until there are 4 permits available.  However, thread 1, which gets a permit upon calling acquire(), only releases 2 permits, which is not enough to unblock thread 4.  Meanwhile, thread 2, which is the only thread for which there are sufficient permits, is not the next to be assigned, so it doesn't get the permits.

Your modified code runs fine because the threads don't block when they try to get a semaphore; they just try again, going to the back of the line.  Eventually thread 2 reaches the front of the line and is thus next to be assigned, and so gets its permits.

Comment: Nice explanation. Thanks for you time. I missed to understand "the current thread is next to be assigned permits" line.